# libgdx disable touch while action is ongoing

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I cannot figure out, how to temporary disable the `DragListener` while there is an ongoing `Action` on the `Actor`. When I touch the `Actor` while there is an ongoing `Action` it gets interrupted and the new `Action` is executed, which leads to a "drift" of the `Actor`. e.g. I shake the `Actor`, but when it is interrupted, the following `Action` is based on the interrupted position of the `Actor`.

Adding Actions inside `touchUp` method:

```
RotateByAction rotL = new RotateByAction();
rotL.setAmount(-3);
rotL.setDuration(0.05f);

RotateByAction rotR = new RotateByAction();
rotR.setAmount(6);
rotR.setDuration(0.05f);

RotateByAction rotBack = new RotateByAction();
rotBack.setAmount(-3);
rotBack.setDuration(0.05f);

SequenceAction seq = new SequenceAction();
seq.addAction(rotL);
seq.addAction(rotR);
seq.addAction(rotBack);

temp.setOrigin(temp.getWidth()/2,temp.getHeight()/2);

temp.addAction(seq);
```

I tried to do something like this inside the Render method of the `Actor`:

```
if (this.getActions().size > 0){//or hasActions()
            this.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
        }
        else{
            this.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        }
```

But that leaves the `Actor` untouchable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do instead is use [`Actions.touchable`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html#touchable-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable-) to disable touch at the start of your action and then enable it again at the end. You can also string multiple actions together, using [`sequence`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html#sequence-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Action...-) or [`parallel`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html#parallel-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Action...-).

```
temp.addAction(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.touchable(Touchable.disabled),
    rotL,
    rotR,
    rotBack,
    Actions.touchable(Touchable.enabled)
));
```